# Closing ChannelFuture after bind

Tags: java, netty

I'm looking at the [following netty example](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/example/echo/EchoServer.html) - a simple echo client and server. When the server bidns to the port, we're waiting for the bind to be complete by calling sync(). After this, the channel is being closed as follows:

```
ChannelFuture f = b.bind(PORT).sync();
// Wait until the server socket is closed.
f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Question: Why close the channel? Will this not close the channel that accepts connections?

Comment: I believe I found out. f.channel().closeFuture() actually does not close the future but only gets a reference to the future which is triggered when close is called. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We're not waiting for the bind to complete in any way here. It has completed. It isn't a blocking method, or an asynchronous one with a Future.

Comment: Is it used to block the application until
the server channel is closed..? I'm not sure

Comment: @EJP: If it has already completed, then what exactly is the ChannelFuture returned from bind().sync()?